# React-Router shows nothing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried to upgrade my old react app to the new react-router version 2.

I made an simpler version from my code as fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/w1uo8mxe/

```
let Router = ReactRouter.Router;
let Route = ReactRouter.Route;
let browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hallo aus Home!
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route handler={MyApp} path="/">
      <Route handler={Home} path="/" />
    </Route>
  </Router>

), document.querySelector('.app'));
```

Nothing shows up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things have changed in `React-Router`.

At the top of your file, add IndexRoute:

`let IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;`

Then your Route config should become:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={MyApp} path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={Home}></IndexRoute>
    </Route>
  </Router>

), document.querySelector('.app'));
```

Updated JsFiddle (I added a push ('/') since otherwise JsFiddle won't route correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/5zexxxe9/

[More information about the configuration here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day!